# Command Binding Failure in MenuItem

Tags: wpf, binding, command, menuitem

I have the following `MenuItem` template in a resource dictionary

```
<Style x:Key="RecentMenuItem" 
       TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.LoadRecentItemCommand}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Header}"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}. {1}">
                            <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" 
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}"/>
                            <Binding Path="FullFileName"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is used like

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="FILE">
        ...
        <MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
                  AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count, 
                                             Mode=OneWay, 
                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RecentMenuItem}"/>
    <MenuItem/>
```

The binding on the `Command` is not working (I can see this with Snoop[dog]).

**What is wrong with the above command binding and how can I fix it?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: maybe you need to remove `Header="_Recent Studies"` or you need to bind to `HeaderTemplate` **EDIT** or to `FullFileName`

Comment: If you want to click the child `MenuItem`s, then surely you need to add your `CommandBehaviour` objects to them, instead of to their parent item?

Comment: @Sheridan I have attempted this method in the PS of the question. This does not even fire for some reason!?

Comment: @Killercam The child would need to bind to the parent's DataContext to access `LoadRecentItemCommand` and `Header`... are you doing that?

Comment: @nmclean I think I am with `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.LoadRecentFileCommand}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
`

Comment: @Killercam `{Binding}` only refers to the header when inside the HeaderTemplate. On the CommandParameter setter it would need to bind to self: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Header}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, it is the Command itself that is not firing. It is `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.LoadRecentItemCommand}" />
` that is not working and I don't know why?

Comment: @Killercam so your `LoadRecentItemCommand` doesn't fired? Do your Command binding work in other cases? There are some Binding Errors?

Comment: Yes, there are binding errors and in other cases the command is called fine. I have other parts of the code when I use `="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.LoadRecentItemCommand}"` and these are fine... Any ideas?

Comment: when you use Snoop can you see the Object in the DataContext or do i miss interpret your Binding maybe there is your problem

Comment: The Command binding is erroneous. This suggest the binding expression I am using is wrong, but I am unsure how to amend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked just fine... i got the full file name in my command parameter: Here command is defined in my window's VM, so you will have to update it accordingly (if you used usercontrol).

```
     <Menu>
          <MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RecentMenuItem}"/>
    </Menu>


    <Style x:Key="RecentMenuItem" 
       TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding FullName}"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding Path="FullName"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This is still not working. One aspect is that the Windo is of type `MahAppsControls:MetroWindow` I have obviously replaced this and it still does not work. SOrry about this...

Comment: did your menu get populated using this approach? did you get any errors in output window? coz it worked at my end

Comment: The hierarchy is `<Menu><MenuItem>` then this `<MenuItem>` as I show in the question. The parent of the `MenuItem` I am populating with a binding is itself a `MenuItem`...